# Unbiased estimator of $1/(1-a)$

Tags: poisson-distribution, estimators, unbiased-estimator

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be Poisson with parameter $a$. I am looking for a unbiased estimator of $h(a)=\frac{1}{1-a}$

Let  $T$ be a statistic and $g(t)$ be it's pmf. Then if we have $E(T)= h(a)$ then $T$ is unbiased for $h$.
So we must have

$$\frac{e^a}{1-a}= \sum _k \frac{g(k)a^k}{k!}   $$

If $ 0<a<1 $ we can expand left hand side and get the values of $ g(k) $ by equating corresponding coefficients. But in this case I'm not able to get the estimator. I am also having difficulty to figure out what to do if $ a>1 $

In general, if I have the parameter $f(a)$ given by the power series
$$f(a) = \sum _{k \ge 0} b_k a^k $$, I can find the probability mass function of a statistic which is an unbiased estimator for $f(a)$ but I am stuck at getting the actual statistic for the same.

Any help is appreciated. I have asked the same question in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4313288/unbiased-estimator-of-1-1-a-when-random-variables-are-poissona) but I did not get any answer there.

Comment: What’s an unbiased estimator for $\alpha?$ what happens when you substitute that in your transformed parameter and take the expectation?

Comment: It looks like bad things will happen if $a=1$. Can you exclude this case?

Comment: @StephanKolassa: or is this a hint that there is _no_ unbiased estimator for this function of $a$?

Comment: Assuming the $X_i$ are independent, their sum is a minimal sufficient statistic and has a Poisson distribution with parameter $na.$  Thus, your question reduces to the case $n=1,$ which you can analyze directly.

Comment: @whuber I do not understand how my question is reducing to $n=1$, the statistic should be a function of $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$

Comment: Yes indeed: isn't the sum of the $X_i$ a function of them?  Perhaps the concept you need is [minimal sufficient statistic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=minimal+sufficient+statistic).